# Modify Task.json at build step design time

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

i wanted to modify task.json on runtime means when i configure my CI task in vsts or tfs.

I created an extension that contribute a build task.
Through this build task i wanted to do something like this, i have done in jenkins. Please Refer screenshot: [image: Jenkin ScreenShot]

1-Requirement) in this image we add global variable(fields) at runtime on clicking Add Global Variables button. It generates two fields one for GVName and another for its value.

2-Requirement) When we select global variable then respective value field change at runtime means it can be dropbox(picklist) or input field that depends on GV type.

3-Requirement) On Job design time we make an ajax call to server that return true/false on based of value we shows error like in image 2.

Is these requirements are feasible in VSTS task.json? If yes, can you help me to solve this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, but it can list the available items that returned from the server.

For example:

```
"inputs": [
 {
      "name": "APIURL",
      "type": "connectedService:Generic",
      "label": "API URL",
      "required": true,
      "helpMarkDown": ""
    },
      {
        "name": "List1",
        "type": "pickList",
        "label": "List4",
        "defaultValue": "",
        "required": false,
        "helpMarkDown": ""
      }
  ],
  "sourceDefinitions": [
    {
      "target": "List1",
      "endpoint": "home/jsontest",
      "selector": "jsonpath:$[*].id",
      "authKey": "$(APIURL)"
    }
  ],
```

A thread that may benefit you: [Using a web API in task.json to fill picklists buildtask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48095492/using-a-web-api-in-task-json-to-fill-picklists-buildtask)

Comment: Thanks starian for your quick response, my problem is generating input fields at design time not filling those input field(or dataSource binding).

Comment: Is it possible to generate input fields on button click ? If yes, then help me.

Comment: What do you mean design time? This is used to edit task of build definition.

Comment: No, but it can display additional input fields per to other control (e.g. checkbox or if a input box is not empty)

Comment: Hi starian, yes it is used to edit task of build definition, have you look snapshot with this question

Comment: Yes, I had, what's the problem?

Comment: Problem is , find out the way to generate picklist and input types dynamically or clicking on button(like in snapshot 1)

Comment: No, it is not supported in VSTS, the input types need to be defined in task.json and can be hidden in UI and display per to the condition.

Comment: Hi starian i found a link, but not understand , can you take a look into this https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/55149/is-there-a-way-to-create-fields-dynamically-for-a.html#reply-form

Comment: This is what I said that you can hidden the elements per to the condition (visibleRule), you can refer to the source code of Azure App Service deploy task https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeployment/task.json