# VSTS Build Task - How To Generate Dropdown List from Result Set

Tags: drop-down-menu, azure-devops, dropdown, dropdownbox

As part of my VSTS build/release definition set up, I would like to populate a dropdown list from the results of a preceding query. For instance, I want the query to return a list of all packages from an external repository and let's just say there are a total of 10 packages stored in that repository.

I then want the entire array of 10 packages displayed in a dropdown list, thereby ensuring that they can then be selected individually.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t add dropdown list control to build/release definition, but you can custom build/release task to add a PickList control through VSTS extension.

There are some threads can help you:

[Using a web API in task.json to fill picklists buildtask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48095492/using-a-web-api-in-task-json-to-fill-picklists-buildtask)

[How to display “Area path” in VSTS build task input PickList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801086/how-to-display-area-path-in-vsts-build-task-input-picklist)

[Service endpoints – Data sources](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sriramb/2016/09/15/service-endpoints-data-sources/)

Comment: Those suggestions look like just what I need. Thank you.