# VSTS Extension : Populate work-item type based on process template

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-extensions

I am working on VSTS extension and I have requirement to populate work item types to combo box based on project's process template .

for example : If user have project with agile template work item types should load accordingly and If user use project with scrum template different set of work item types should available in combo-box (note that in below list we got "Impediment" in Scrum instead of "Issue" in agile)

process template : **Agile**

- Task
- Bug
- Issue
- Epic
- Feature
- Test case

process template :  **Scrum**

- Task
- Bug
- Impediment
- Epic
- Feature
- Test case

as we just have control over task.json file to define UI, I found it not possible to dynamically populate different set of combo box items. Is there any way to achieve this? Please show some light on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use PickList in your customize task, one for process template  such as Agile/Scrum, another child picklist dynamically change based on the template you selected above.

Just put the value of all work item types corresponding to the process template in child picklist, the UI should be something as below:

[image]

More details about how to achieve this through API please refer this link: [How to display "Area path" in VSTS build task input PickList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801086/how-to-display-area-path-in-vsts-build-task-input-picklist)

You could also take a look at below tutorials:

There are some threads can help you:

- [Using a web API in task.json to fill picklists buildtask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48095492/using-a-web-api-in-task-json-to-fill-picklists-buildtask)
- [Service endpoints – Data sources](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sriramb/2016/09/15/service-endpoints-data-sources/)

---

About how to get all work item types, you could use **[Work Item Types - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/work%20item%20types/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1)**  Rest API, this will return  the list of work item types for a project. One Team Project could only have one kind of process template:

```
GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/wit/workitemtypes?api-version=4.1
```